# Ruby Hash: can't convert String into Integer TypeError

Tags: ruby, hash, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

Currently getting a `Ruby Hash: can't convert String into Integer` error. The code fails on the edit_id line.

I've tried many different solutions from similar questions already posted on SE, but unfortunately none of them have worked.

Hash:

```
{"downloadID"=>115, "PageID"=>nil, "title"=>"hi", "dlLink"=>"http://www.a.com", "imgSrc"=>"http://www.a.com", "caption"=>"aaaa", "dlLive"=>nil, "createdAt"=>nil, "user_id"=>7}
```

Code:

```
#edit download
put '/view1/downloadedit' do
  data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  puts data
  edit_id = data["downloadID"]
  puts edit_id
  @download = Download.get(:download_id => edit_id)
  puts data
  if @download.update(data)
    status 201
    puts 'edit saved okay'
  else
    status 201
    puts 'edit failed to SAVE'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JSON.parse(request.body.read)` gives you an array of hash. So the fix is `edit_id = data[0]["downloadID"]`. Write `p data` instead of `puts data`, you will see the `data` is an array of hash.